# Couchbase 2.0.0 Node no suitable image found

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchnode

I was using Couchbase nodejs module version **2.0.0-beta4** for some time already, and today I wanted to switch to the latest version which is **2.0.0**.

After installing the 2.0.0 version I don't seem to be able to run my application anymore, I've tried to find the source of problem, so I tested with a file where I only wrote the require function like:

```
var couchbase = require("couchbase");
```

Still this file doesn't run and I got the following error:

> [ERROR] 11:23:53 Error
>   Error: > dlopen(/PATH/TO/NODEJS/PROJECT/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>
> ```
>    /PATH/TO/NODEJS/PROJECT/node_modules/couchbase/prebuilt/win/x64/couchbase_impl.node: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
>    at Object..node (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/lib/hook.js:55:17)
>    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>    at require (module.js:380:17)
>    at bindings (/PATH/TO/NODEJS/PROJECT/node_modules/couchbase/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:74:15)
>    at tryLoadBinding (/PATH/TO/NODEJS/PROJECT/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:132:31)
>    at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH/TO/NODEJS/PROJECT/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:150:17)
>    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
> ```

#### Update: I forgot to mention that I am using MacOS X 10.9.5 and nodejs v0.10.32

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at: http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/JSCBC-87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my problem is solved and it was pretty stupid of me, there didn't seem anything wrong with node-gyp, but when I checked the log file **builderror.log**, I've found something interesting, I needed to accept the xcode license agreement, since xcode has been updated recently, so I did that, removed the couchbase nodejs module, and installed it again, then every thing worked smoothly (even a disturbing bug disappeared)

Many, thanks and I hope this will help someone in future.